# is it possible to change case model cmmn in flowable to another while processing

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, flowable

I'm new to flowable, I have the intention to use it as a case management system, but I have an important question about it which is: is it possible to change case model CMMN in flowable to another while processing? for example, I received a loan request but while processing this request to determine if it's possible or not, a situation happens which requires changing the loan request to a donation request.
please note that I want them as separate cases.

I really appreciate your help!:) 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the case model to an entirely different case model while a case is started is not possible.

What you'll need to do is to determine the type of case you want to start when you receive a request and before you start a case instance.

In case you model your cases to be adaptable and that they need to change. You can have a dedicated Service Task logic that will start a new case instance (donation request) and terminate the loan request.